# How to login into Moodle from a different website

Tags: php, authentication, moodle

For this I am on localhost host which is serving two sites mysite and my.moodle

what is the process of logging into my/a moodle user account from mysite? I understand I need a authentication token however have no idea on how to obtain one.

I have a basic form below. can anyone advice or point in right direction.

```
<form action="https://my.moodle.com/login/token.php" method="post">
<input type="username" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password" >
</form>
```

and how do I use that token?

thanks

Comment: The token.php file in Moodle echoes out some JSON when it completes (containing the token), so I think rather than having a form actually POST to it, you'd probably want to have an AJAX request fire off and go and post that data and return the JSON to parse.

Comment: the JSON it returns as follows:

{
  "error": "Web service is not available (it doesn't exist or might be disabled)",
  "stacktrace": null,
  "debuginfo": null,
  "reproductionlink": null
}

what is the service parameter or where in my moodle install/admin can I find a list of the services?

Comment: You need to enable web services on your Moodle first.

Comment: they're already enabled

Comment: I haven't used it myself before, so not 100% sure. Have you checked your Administration -> Plugins -> Web Services -> Overview?